# I can't get basic Slick carousel to work?

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I'm just trying to get a simple carousel to work, but the page just shows me pictures without any carousel. How do I fix this? I'm following the 'Getting Started' guide from: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div><img src="images/image1.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image2.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image3.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image4.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image5.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image13.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image6.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image21.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image3.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image9.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image12.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/image13.png"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
    $('.variable-width').slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 300,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          centerMode: true,
          variableWidth: true
    });
    $('.autoplay').slick({
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I already have `"$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });"` too. do I actually need to create my own .js file? I only have the slick folder, images folder, and this .html file on my root.

Comment: `setting-name: setting-value` is an example of the syntax. If you remove that line, it'll probably work, using the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually initializing the `div`. `setting-name : setting-value` is pseudo code, indicating that the name and value need replacing.

An example of a proper initialization would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-class').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      variableWidth: true
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvwLotua/)